# Recyclerview last item not shown inside coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

My last item inside recyclerview is not shown. The top bar should remain visible once it gains focus. It should not scroll upwards.
My code is below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="haygot.togyah.app.newDesign.home.FlingBehaviour"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/leaderboard_iv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_leaderboard_icon" />

                    <haygot.togyah.app.widget.TextView.TextViewPlus
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/doubts"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leaderboard_iv"
                        android:alpha="0"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="What would you like to learn today?"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/CollapsingToolbarTitle" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/doubts"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_doubt_home" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/home_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_dash_profile_icon"

                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <haygot.togyah.app.widget.TextView.TextViewPlus
                    android:id="@+id/message"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/home_icon"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_36dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:letterSpacing="-.03"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
                    android:minLines="3"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/app_text_size_xxxlarge"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:customFont="@string/font_proxima_nova_bold"
                    tools:text="Hello Anudeep, \n let's learn something\n new today!" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:id="@+id/subjects_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_small"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_small"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_small"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As I move upwards, the last item in the recycler is partially visible.
How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to set minimum height for the toolbar and collapsing toolbar:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: Perfect answer! but i didn't need to set it for Toolbar as my toolbar has 'android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize' so i only had to set it for CollapsingToolbarLayout

Answer (score 0):

Make your `AppBarLayout` to have specific height, save that value in `dimens.xml`. And apply that much margin from bottom to `RecyclerView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    ...
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    .../>
```